# htaccess rewrite for my domain doesn't work

Tags: .htaccess

Hi I tried to replace the domain with .htaccess

This is my domain:

```
http://domain.com/categories.php?catid=7&catname=Buero-und-Schreibwaren
```

I tried this but it doesn't work. What do I false?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-z\-_0-9])\.html$ /categories.php?katid=$1&katname=$2
```

I want to have a domain like these:

```
http://domain.com/categories/Buero-und-Schreibwaren/
```

Comment: You have 2 inputs (categories and Buero-und-Schreibwaren) and you want 3 groups. You should do domain like this http://domain.com/categories/Buero-und-Schreibwaren/7/ where the last number is catid

Comment: Ok what I must change to have my result?

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 inputs catid and catname so when you set up your new urls you need to pass both parameters.

for example :

http://domain.com/categories.php?catid=7&catname=Buero-und-Schreibwaren will become http://domain.com/categories/Buero-und-Schreibwaren/7

```
RewriteRule ^categories/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([0-9]+)$ /categories.php?catid=$2&catname=$1
```

You can try the above but you will understand how it works much better if you follow through with this tutorial first : http://www.wisdombay.com/articles/basic%20guide%20to%20mod_rewrite.htm

Comment: Hi thanks for your help. I have changed it to your version. Now I get an 500 Internal Server Error. What I had do wrong?

Comment: Please post your full htaccess file. Did you go through the tutorial?

Comment: RewriteEngine On

Options +FollowSymlinks RewriteBase /mc/
RewriteRule ^categories/([0-9]+)$/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/ /categories.php?catid=$2&catname=$1

Comment: Maybe `+FollowSymlinks` is already turned on in your httpd.conf or similar. Try to strip that out and test if it works, if not simply re add it.

Answer (score 0):

The `AllowOverride` for your DocRoot is allowed? if not, try this :

```
<Directory /var/www/www.example.com>
  ...
  Allowoverride ALL
</Directory>
```